# How to search for string if it contains whitespace in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

Currently, in search, I am looking for a string that contains some characters:

```
func search(for keyword: String?) {
    self.keyword = keyword
    guard let keyword = keyword?
        .folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: nil)
        .lowercased(),
        !keyword.isEmpty else {
        filteredNames = names
        return
    }
    filteredNames = names
        .filter { $0.title.lowercased()
            .folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: nil)
            .contains(keyword)
        }
}
```

The problem is that when the list is bigger, it shows more than expected.
I would use not .contain(keyword), but .starts(with: keywoard), but then it would miss some results.

let's say I have an array of:
let myArray = ["name", "my name", "some name", "else string", "string", "stringname"]
so when looking for 'ame' not it shows all that contains the string, and what I want is to shown only if the word in an array starts with that. So when typing 'name' it should return me "name", "some name" but **NOT** the "stringname"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this -

```
extension String {
    // Assumption: Both `keyword` & `self` are already lowercased
    func hasMatch(for keyword: String) -> Bool {
        let comps = self
            .folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: nil)
            .components(separatedBy: " ")
        return (comps.first(where: { $0.starts(with: keyword) }) != nil)
    }
}
```

Now your filter logic can use it like this -

```
filteredNames = names
    .filter { $0.title.lowercased()
        .hasMatch(for: keyword)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is searching with Regular Expression and `range(of:options:)`

The benefit is no extra objects are created, it's O(n) and you can specify the case insensitive and diacritics insensitive options at the same time. The `\b` in the regex pattern represents *word boundaries*

```
let keyword = "name"
let myArray = ["name", "my name", "some name", "else string", "string", "stringname"]

let filtered = myArray.filter {
    $0.range(of: "\\b\(keyword)", options: [.regularExpression, .caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil
}
print(filtered)
```

Comment: This was the answer I was going to post but without the \b at the end since I believe OP wants words that starts with the search string, like "nameless"

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Right, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You could split each `String` by their whitespace and match each component.

```
let searchTerm = "name"
let myArray = ["name", "my name", "some name", "else string", "string", "stringname"]

let matches = myArray.filter {
  $0.components(separatedBy: " ").contains {
    $0.hasPrefix(searchTerm)
  }
}
```

Improvements left to the reader:

- Split string by any kind of whitespace
- Case-insensitive, diacritic-insensitive search